# Using RobotKit/Sphero SDK on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sphero-api

I try to connect Sphere and drive it thru iPhone.

I include ExternalAccessory.framework, Foundation.framework, and RobotKit.framework under Build Phases binary.

I have following in ViewController.h

```
#import <RobotKit/RobotKit.h>
```

and I am using following in ViewController.m

```
[[RKRobotProvider sharedRobotProvider] openRobotConnection];
[RKRollCommand sendCommandWithHeading:0.0 velocity:0.5];
```

However there is error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKRollCommand", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKRobotProvider", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Plz help! And Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the [beta branch on GitHub](https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/Beta)! for arm64 support.  A new release version based on this Beta is due out later this week.